# Show Mapbox using Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, mapbox, android-jetpack-compose, mapbox-android

Versions

- Mapbox `10.6.0-rc.1`
- Gradle `7.2.1`

When I run an app mapbox tiles are black.
My code:

```
@Composable
fun MapboxScreen() {

    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background)
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        AndroidView(
            modifier = Modifier,
            factory = { context ->
                ResourceOptionsManager.getDefault(
                    context,
                    context.getString(R.string.mapbox_access_token)
                )

                MapView(context).apply {
                    getMapboxMap().loadStyleUri(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS) {
                         cameraOptions {
                              zoom(19.0)
                         }
                    }
                }
            )
         }
     }
```

Also I tried tokens in another app (non-compose) and there map tiles are shown correctly.

Was trying code as it is shown in this post: [Mapbox map is black using jetpack compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66682187/mapbox-map-is-black-using-jetpack-compose) but it wasn't working...

Also tried older Mapbox v9.

[Phone Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1oiS.jpg)

Comment: Any updates? Seems like for me background color removal doesn’t help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to remove in `themes.xml` item with background

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/neutral_10</item> // remove this line
</style>
```

and it worked like a charm.

Mapbox probably take these parameter as foreground color for mapbox.

Also posted more in details here https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-maps-android/issues/1422

Comment: Also I believe this is not a compose only thing. Mapbox also have this bug when working with `xml`. Had it happened to me a while ago on `'com.mapbox.maps:android:10.9.1'`

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `MapInitOptions.antialiasingSampleCount`

```
mapView = MapView(
  inflater.context,
  MapInitOptions(
    inflater.context,
    antialiasingSampleCount = 4,
  )
)
```